# Error in Creating a Node Table in Sql-server 2017

Tags: sql-server, graph-databases, sql-graph, sql-server-2017-graph

I have just installed Sql Server 2017 and it's Management studio 
for practicing Graph database but I have problem creating a Node table. I get an error while creating a Node table
and I can not see anything related to the graphs :

```
CREATE TABLE Users (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NickName VARCHAR(100)) AS NODE;
```

The error :

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'
```

Comment: Can you do `SELECT @@VERSION` to make sure you have the right version for this syntax ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4019088) - 13.0.1742.0 (X64)   Jul  5 2017 23:41:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 6.3 <X64> (Build 16299: )  I got this !!!! what should i do??

Comment: OMG !!! it says that the management studio in for sql server 2016 !! but I just run run it from sql server 2017 !!!! even the entrance shape is different !!!!

Comment: So, you have SSMS 17, which is a *client tool* connecting to SQL Server 2016 (the server). If you want to work with Nodes, you presumably need to find a SQL Server 2017 instance to connect to. (If you already had 2016 installed when you attempted to install 2017 and are sure it did install the server then perhaps it's been installed as a named instance - check what SQL Server services you have running)

Comment: @PTTT you have your answer, try to upgrade your server to SQL Server 2017.

Comment: WOW thank you thank you thank you.. I know I should not use comments to thank someone in here but I have to say thank you :)

Comment: Hm, they say you should not put answers in comments and that comment of @Damien_The_Unbeliever looks like an answer rather than comment.

Comment: You can also practice against Azure SQL DB, so if you have an Azure subscription, i[ts easy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal).